# Mismatch Error in Python even with perfect Output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this as my assignment:-

**Write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. Enter 7, 2, bob, 10, and 4 and match the output below.

Desired Output-

Invalid input

Maximum is 10

Minimum is 2**

I wrote the following code for the same-

```
largest = None
smallest = None
count=0
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")

    if num == "done" :
        break
    try:
        fval=float(num)
        count=count+1

        if(fval == None):
            largest=None
            smallest=None

        if(largest<fval):
            largest=int(fval)
        if(count==1):
            smallest=fval                    
        else:
            if(int(fval) < smallest):
                    smallest=int(fval)



    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue






print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minumum is", smallest)
```

It is working fine too. I am able to fetch the smallest and largest entries. But, at the end, the editor is not accepting this code. Any possible error in the code logic?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: It doesn't work fine. Try running what you posted here.

Comment: Sir, could you please tell me where I am making the mistake?

Comment: Are you running this with python2.x or python 3.y?

Comment: Running this on python 3.y .

Comment: The reference input and output contradict the description of the program's behaviour, since "done" is never entered and thus the program should never terminate or print out the minimuim and maximum numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is a mismatch between your version of python and the version that the code judge runs to evaluate your code.

What's the difference? `None` can be compared to integers (actually, almost everything is comparable in python2). Look at this:

**Python 2.x**

```
In [211]: None < 123456
Out[211]: True
```

**Python 3.x**

```
In [152]: None < 123456
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-cf9ae210e7ad> in <module>()
----> 1 None < 123456

TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()
> <ipython-input-152-cf9ae210e7ad>(1)<module>()
----> 1 None < 123456
```

How does that matter to you? Well, for the first iteration, this line of code:

```
if(largest < fval):
```

Will compare `fval` with `largest`, which has an initial value of `None`.

Just another note, be wary about `input` in python2 vs python3. The two behave differently. The former will throw a `NameError` when you type a string.

---

I would recommend initialising your `largest` and `smallest` to valid values, like this:

```
largest = float('-inf')
smallest = float('inf')
```

Comment: I'd also note that `input` in Py2 tries to evaluate the input, so typing `done` in will throw `NameError`.

Comment: Thank you sir!! It  worked with largest = float('-inf') and 
smallest = float('inf').

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 Actually... input shouldn't be a problem if OP is submitting this to python 3.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Then their python 2 interpreter is very different to mine.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I mean the original code in the question. It doesn't work as expected with python 3 and it's even worse with python 2.

Comment: @Goyo With python3 the only problem is the None comparison. With python2 the only possible issue is the name error because of `done`. I can only speculate exactly what the problem was for OP.

Answer (score 1):

I will use `isinstance` to check if the input is a integer and I will store all the elements in a `list`to, at the end of my program, call `min` and `max`.

Here's a code that works:

```
import ast

inputs = []
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")

    if num == "done" :
        break
    try:
        # Check if the input is a number
        if num.isnumeric():
            # If so, convert the string to a number
            number = ast.literal_eval(num)
            # If it's an int, store it in the list
            if isinstance(number, int):
                inputs.append(number)
            else:
                # If not, raise and exception
                raise ValueError("Not an integer!")

    except ValueError as ve:
        print(ve)

# Show the desired output
print("Maximum is", max(inputs))
print("Minumum is", min(inputs))
```

Answer (score 1):

Some advises:

- Only put code in the `try`-block that you actually expect to raise the exception.
- Do not do Pokemon Exception handling (Gotta catch 'em all). Only handle exceptions you actually expect.
- Why do you (try to) convert the user input to `float` if you are requsted to check for integers?
- `float(num)` will never be `None`, so checking for it does not make any sense.

Finally, I'd come up with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    minimum = maximum = None

    while True:
        user_input = input('Enter a number: ')

        if user_input == 'done':
            break

        try:
            integer = int(user_input)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input')
        else:
            if minimum is None or integer < minimum:
                minimum = integer

            if maximum is None or integer > maximum:
                maximum = integer

    print('Maximum is', maximum)
    print('Minimum is', minimum)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code i wrote working fine in all the terminals, try this one it will work.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
cnt = 0
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done" : break

    elif(num == ""):
         print("InValid num")
         break
    try :
        val = int(num)
        #print(val)
        #break
    except ValueError:
        val = -1
        print("Invalid input")
        continue


    if cnt == 0 :
        largest = val
        smallest = val
    elif val > largest :
        largest = val
    elif val < smallest :
        smallest = val

    cnt = cnt +  1  




print("Maximum is",largest)
print("Minimum is",smallest)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        n = int(num)
        if smallest is None or n < smallest:
            smallest = n
        if largest is None or n > largest:
            largest = n
    except ValueError:
    # num cannot be converted to an int
        print ("Invalid input")

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: Hi guys! I am getting the "mismatch error" anybody happens to know why

Answer (score 0):

largest = None
smallest = None

while True:
    try:
        num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
        if num == "done":
            break
        if largest is None:
            largest = int(num)
        if int(num) > largest:
            largest = int(num)
        if smallest is None:
            smallest = int(num)
        if int(num) < smallest:
            smallest = int(num)
    except:
        print ("Invalid input")

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)

Comment: You should use the 'code' markup for code such that it displays correctly

Comment: Yes, code markup is important! check [Code Blocks](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks)

Answer (score 0):

```
largest = 0
smallest = 999999
inval = "notdone"
x = 0

while True :
    inval = input("Enter a number: ")
    if (inval == "done") :
        break
    else :
        try:
            x = int(inval)
            if (x > largest) :
                largest = x
            if (x < smallest) :
                smallest = x           
        except :
            print("Invalid input")  
    
print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).